# Remove items from an array where they match a certain criteria in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match, unset

I have an array of products and i need to remove all of them which have a reference to webinar

The PHP version I am using is 5.2.9

```
$category->products
```

example:

```
    [6] => stdClass Object
            (
                [pageName] => another_title_webinar
                [title] => Another Webinar Title
            )

        [7] => stdClass Object
            (
                [pageName] => support_webinar
                [title] => Support Webinar
            )
[8] => stdClass Object
            (
                [pageName] => support
                [title] => Support
            )
```

In this case number 8 would be left but the other two would be stripped...

Could anyone help?

Comment: Looks like a case for array_filter() with a callback to test for "webinar" in the object page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [array_filter()](http://php.net/array-filter). Assuming you run PHP 5.3+, this would do the trick:

```
$this->categories = array_filter($this->categories, function ($obj) {
    if (stripos($obj->title, 'webinar') !== false) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
});
```

For PHP 5.2:

```
function filterCategories($obj)
{
    if (stripos($obj->title, 'webinar') !== false) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

$this->categories = array_filter($this->categories, 'filterCategories');
```

Comment: Your code is wrong you are making `webinar` haystack instead of needle  see http://eval.in/4811

Comment: Early morning hours ugh.. sorry about that! @Baba, thanks for the correction. :)

Comment: Then you just need to move the anonymous function to a normal function and use it's name as callback. As Hugo below already mentioned. And I also edited mine. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
$category->products = array_filter($category->products, function ($v) {
    return stripos($v->title, "webinar") === false;
});
```

[Simple Online Demo](http://eval.in/4810)

Comment: Andy upgrade  that was last supported `26-Feb-2009` ...... see http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php ... you are more problems than you think ....

Comment: Thanks for the eval.in link...well worth bookmarking unfortunately i am using 5.2.9

Answer (score 1):

You could use the array_filter method. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

```
function stripWebinar($el) {
  return (substr_count($el->title, 'Webinar')!=0);
}

array_filter($category->products, "stripWebinar")
```